# What to do if user folder has a space in directory?

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, yolo

I'm currently trying to train a Yolov3 model (by wiz young). The format of the annotation file is:

```
index directory width height ....
```

My Absolute Directory is: `C:\User\My Name\YOLOv3_TensorFlow\misc\JPEGImages\object.jpg`

It reads line by line and determines the values based on the position. Due to the space in my user name, it confuses the `Name\YOLOv3_TensorFlow\misc\JPEGImages\object.jpg` as width instead and returns me `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Name\\YOLOv3_TensorFlow\\misc\\JPEGImages\\Van_(52).jpg'`

Am i wrong to put the directory as \ (using windows) as i believe the original code was for Linux.
Also, are there any methods to prevent the space from interferring?

I believe this portion of the code is relevant:

```
if 'str' not in str(type(line)):
        line = line.decode()
    s = line.strip().split(' ')
    assert len(s) > 8, 
    line_idx = int(s[0])
    pic_path = s[1]
    img_width = int(s[2])
    img_height = int(s[3])
    s = s[4:]
```

Comment: What is "it"?..

Comment: Just edited. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following to wrap the directory in string quotes and add the r symbol to the string.
Example below to illustrate.

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("C:\Users\ali\Pictures\spaced folder\object 1.png")
```

Gives the following unicode error:
`File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX`

However, adding an r in front of string quotes does the trick.

```
image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\ali\Pictures\spaced folder\object 1.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Wrap the directory path in quotes in the annotation file. That is the standard way in Windows to deal with paths with spaces in them.
2. This may sound extreme, but as a longtime Mac user who now has a Windows box in my current job, I recommend getting Windows Subsystem for Linux. And then do all your tensorflow work there instead of in the Windows environment. Avoid spaces in directory names (in linux, this is frowned upon, even though it's typical in Windows).
3. If you want to stay in the Windows environment and can't for some reason wrap the path in quotes, you could simply move the data to a directory outside your user folder, one that doesn't have spaces in it...

Comment: Thank you so much! 1 did not work for me but 3 worked like a charm!